# ERROR: column "own_amount" is of type numeric but expression is of type character varying

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jhipster, liquibase

I have next field in db, create using current entities

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "own_amount", precision = 21, scale = 4, nullable = false)
private BigDecimal ownAmount;
```

Liquibase csv

```
id;own_amount
1;37454
```

Error

```
ERROR: column "own_amount" is of type numeric but expression is of type character varying
How to fix this
```

Comment: If you put `1;37454,0` it is working ? ( in the second line )

Comment: @Fizik26 same result((

Comment: How did you type this column in loadData tag in your Liquibase migration? Pleas paste code of your migration. See valueNumeric in https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html

Comment: Looks like a bug. @GaëlMarziou I have just jdl enity with "ownAmount BigDecimal required" field, but jhipster generates loadData for it as string <loadData
            file="config/liquibase/data/financial_account.csv"
            separator=";"
            tableName="financial_account"
            context="dev">
            <column name="own_amount" type="string"/>

Comment: Try fixing it manually and then please report the issue with solution on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the generator, it will be [fixed in this pull request](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/9621).

To fix before the next JHipster release, change `string` to `numeric` for the `own_amount` field in your entity's XML changelog file (in the `loadData` tag).